# Laravel Lookup Value in Table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've used some guides online to populate a dropdown box from the database by using the pluck function. This works in create, but when viewing the table and showing the record it only shows the ID not the lookup value from the table it's referencing. I've tried returning the data into the customers.show and altering the view but cannot get it to work.

Controller:

```
    public function show($id)
  {
        $company = Companies::find($id);
        $customers = $this->customersRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

        if (empty($customers)) {
            Flash::error('Customers not found');

            return redirect(route('customers.index'));
        }

        return view('customers.show')
        ->with('customers', $customers)
        ->with('company', $company);
    }
```

Then the view:

```
<!-- Company Id Field -->
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('company_id', 'Company Id:') !!}
    <p>{!! $company->name !!}</p>
</div>
```

I also believe i have the correct relationship setup in the model:

```
 public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Company::class);
    }
```

I believe something is wrong with the `$company = Companies::find($id)` I want it to find the field customers.company_id. If i manually type in the ID of the record from the companies table e.g. 1 it returns data correctly.

In the customers table there's a column company_id which is constrained to the companies table column ID.
Thanks

Comment: Try to return the following: `return view('customers.show', compact("customers", "company"));`

Comment: I think the problem lies with  `$company = Companies::find($id);` i dont want to find the company from the ID field but instead the company_id field. If i manually type in the id e.g. '3' it returns the data i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
return view('customers.show', compact('company', 'customers'));
```

And I'm not really sure what field do you want to display and what exactly is not working.

**EDIT:** If you have a belongsTo relationshop for the company in your customer model you can try this:

```
$customer->company->name
```

Comment: This is the customers table, the company ID references the company table but i want to return companies.name for the ID in the customers.company_id field.

Comment: If you have a belongsTo relationshop for the company in your customer model you can try this: `$customer->company->name`

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Can't believe it was that easy. If you submit as answer i'll mark it.

Answer (score 1):

After spending the past day or so bumping around in the dark, I thought I'd come back and see if I couldn't help cut a clearer path for those who follow.

I'll use my own code so there's yet another example floating out there for that hypothetical person out there.

My Situation: I've got a Job model with a "status" column, but it's just an id. And that's not very helpful.

- Job

  - status
- JobStatus

  - status_id
  - title
  - description

**First Up: The Lookup Table**
The table with the extra information. In case you weren't sure, this model doesn't need to do anything. Just exist and work like it's supposed to.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class JobStatus extends Model
{

    protected $primarykey = "status_id";  //Because my key is not Laravel-standard
}
```

**Second: The "Parent" Table** 
The 'appends' and 'get__Attribute' are yet more hidden goodies in Laravel that automagically expand your model query.

What really threw me off was that I thought the "belongsTo" was supposed to be in the lookup table.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Job extends Model {

    // . . .

    //Can be anything - but 'status' was taken
    protected $appends = ['job_status']; 

    //Needs to be camel case of $appends
    public function getJobStatusAttribute() { 
        return $this->status()->first();
    }

    public function status() {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\JobStatus', 'status', 'status_id');  // Again, not the Laravel-iest keys
    }
```

**Third: The Controller**
Nothing relevant here, but I want to give a full view of what's going on. Just a normal call to the model (with a specialized function).

```
<?php

//. . . .

class AccountController extends Controller {

    public function loadaccount() {

         $job = Job::currentjob();

         return view('account/account', [
             'job' => $job,
         ]);

}
```

**Finally, The View**

```
// account.blade.php

@section('content')

@if($job)
    Progress Report for "{{ $job->title }}"<br/>    
    Status: {{ $job->job_status->title }}<br/>
    {{ $job->job_status->description }}<br/>
</div>
@endif

// . . . . //
```

Hope this helps.

(Worth noting, for honesty's sake, that this answer is basically thanks to this guy:) 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/need-to-append-a-field-from-a-lookup-table-in-my-result-collection